# Exit android app on back pressed

Tags: android

I am building an Android App. How to exit an Android App when back is pressed. Android version is 2.3.3 and above. The Android App goes to previous activity which i don't want.

Comment: clear the back stack. or use a base activity override on pause call finish. extend your activity from it

Comment: override `onBackPressed()` with a `finish()`

Comment: Please accept the most fitting answer, @user3218332

Answer (score 47):

Try this

```
public void onBackPressed(){
Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(a);

}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I put `android:noHistory="true"` for my WelcomeActivity class in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but pressing back button from my WelcomeActivity did not close my app (which is what I wanted); It would take me back to my MainActivity, which is where I called `startActivityForResult()` method to go to WelcomeActivity . I had to use your solution on my WelcomeActivity class for my app to close correctly.

Comment: Good solution.Worked for me.

Answer (score 47):

Some Activities you don't actually want to open again when the back button is pressed, such as Splash Screen Activity, Welcome Screen Activity and Confirmation Windows. Actually, you don't need this in the activity stack. You can do this using=> open Manifest.xml file and add an attribute

> android:noHistory="true"

to these activities.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.shoppingapp.AddNewItems"
    android:label="" 
    android:noHistory="true">
</activity>
```

OR

Sometimes you want to close the entire application on a certain back button press. Here the best practice is to open up the home window instead of exiting the application. For that, you need to override the onBackPressed() method. Usually, this method opens up the top activity in the stack.

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){
Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(a);
}
```

OR

On back button pressed you want to exit that activity and also you don't want to add this to the activity stack. Call finish() inside the onBackPressed() method. It will not close the entire application, it will just go to the previous activity in the stack.

onBackPressed() - Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  finish();
}
```

Comment: I have a Welcome Screen Activity that I put `android:noHistory="true"` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, but pressing the back button kept taking me back to my MainActivity. I also had to override the `onBackPressed()` method as you suggested in order for my back button to close my app when I am in my Welcome Screen Actiivty. I don't know why `android:noHistory="true"` didn't just work.

Comment: awesome code dude ..
   This code for exiting application onbackpressed works very well

Comment: I've been struggling with this for hours and this rocks , thank you <3

Answer (score 40):

You can clear all the back stack doing this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finishAffinity();
}
```

Answer (score 27):

I found an interesting solution which might help.

I implemented this in my onBackPressed()

```
finishAffinity();
finish();
```

FinishAffinity removes the connection of the existing activity to its stack. And then finish helps you exit that activity. Which will eventually exit the application.

Comment: This helped me. :)

Comment: finishAffinity() is the most important before calling finish(). Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

I know its too late, but no one mentioned the code which i used, so It will help others.

this `moveTaskToBack` work as same as Home Button. It leaves the Back stack as it is.

```java
 public void onBackPressed() {
 //  super.onBackPressed();
    moveTaskToBack();
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have more than one screen in history and need all other ones to be ignored.
I recommend using this:

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish();

}
```

Comment: seems too be a good answer for my problem I came across just now. But how to prompt a user whether he really wishes to exit? I wanted to prompt a dialog box stating if he really likes to exit. If clicked on OK exit. cancel remain in the same activity.

Answer (score 9):

```
// Finish current activity
// Go back to previous activity or closes app if last activity
finish()

// Finish all activities in stack and app closes
finishAffinity()

// Takes you to home screen but app isnt closed 
// Opening app takes you back to this current activity (if it hasnt been destroyed)
Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).apply {  
    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    startActivity(this)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In normal way you shouldn't close app - user will moves it to back by pressing home or closing your activities by pressing back.

But you can use this tips:

1) Close old activities after starting the new ones if they not needed in back stack:

```
startActivity(newActivityIntent);
finish();
```

2) You can move task to back (instead of close) if you need http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack(boolean)

3) If you are really need it, you can use `System.exit(0)` but it's **strongly not recommended** and usually says that you have application's architecture problems.

Answer (score 5):

`moveTaskToBack()` is now `Deprecated`

Use :

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin:

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
        val exitIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        exitIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
        exitIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        startActivity(exitIntent)
    }
```

Other codes have problems, some does not work and some needs API classification.

Answer (score 3):

Pop Up

```
     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
       .setTitle("Really Exit?")
       .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    WelcomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }).create().show();
```

}

Set Class to Top of App and no history

```
Intent launchNextActivity;
launchNextActivity = new Intent(B.class, A.class);
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                  

launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(launchNextActivity);
```

enter code here Double back press

```
private static long back_pressed;
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()){
super.onBackPressed();
}
else{
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code `finish();` under your intent to close the activity. So, It will not appear again. This solved mine.

```
startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can exit app wtih this code.

@override
public void onBackPressed()

{

finishAffinity();

System.exit(0);

}

Comment: If it's from loader activity, just add super.onBackPressed().

Comment: If you have opened different activities and want the application to be closed when you exit the activity you are in, you can use the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

As per user experience, pressing back should never exit the application. An alertDialog should come which asks the user if they want to exit the application or they wants to stay on the application. Here is the code :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("DO YOU REALLY WANT TO EXIT ??")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        FirstActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Please also link to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml if you write in Activity tag

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

if we backpressed this activity there is no history my app like click home button, app is background

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the case when you want to prevent your app from going back to the Splash Screen when back is pressed on Main Activity, I add finish() after the intent launcher when I start the Main Activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

Now when you press back on MainActivity, it will exit the app.