# Different onBackPressed for activity and fragment

Tags: java, android

My app flow is:

Activity A -> Activity B (this activity has buttons which on click open fragments)

I want that when I am on Activity B's fragments, on back pressed the flow should be to Activity B and when I am on Activity B then on back pressed app should exit.

I am currently using:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }

    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

It's working fine when back pressed on Activity B's fragments, but it's going to Activity A when pressed back from Activity B(and that too for some reason nothing is being displayed in Activity A).

**EDIT**

My code for calling fragment:

```
faqsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLoginSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
            b1.putString("ComingFrom","Login");
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment faqsFragment = new fragment11Faqs();
            faqsFragment.setArguments(b1);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.framelayoutfaqs,faqsFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(faqsFragment.toString());
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exit android app on back pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253303/exit-android-app-on-back-pressed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `finish()` when you call `Activity B` right after declaring its intent from `ActivityA`

Like this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And you code for backstack is fine in activity b just add `finish()` after `super.onBackPressed();`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }

    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Here is how to add fragment to backstack

```
 Fragment cameraEditing = new Editing(); FragmentManager
 fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); FragmentTransaction 
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.cameraLayout, 
cameraEditing,"cameraEditing"); 
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("cameraEditing");
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: This is exiting the app even when I press back on the fragments

Comment: Did you add the fragments to back stack ?

Comment: can you tell me how do I do that?

Comment: Well when u write the code to add or replace fragment ,you just have to add the line  - addtobackstack() then it will add it to backstack ,you can see the code on Google by how to add fragment to back stack ,then this code will work dear

Comment: That's wrong ,don't pass null ,pass the fragment name there ,better if you see how to add fragment to backstack

Comment: oh okay, and I can't pass fragment name there as it is asking for String

Comment: Let's say your fragment is HomeFrgament then pass"HomeFragment" as a string argument

Comment: I am sorry but it's not working, I have posted my fragment call above in the edited section, please guide me

Comment: Please just look how to add fragment in backstack dear

Comment: And when u do that ,add the code which I answered and let me know if it helped or not

Comment: sure will do :)

Comment: Well I added that in my answer and use it please

Comment: It actually worked by instead of putting finish() i wrote return and it worked with addtobackstack(null)

Comment: I am glad it worked dear ,please accept my answer for others to refer it also

Comment: Happy coding dear